# NetInstall fails when downloading kernelcache

Tags: network, osx-server, netboot

When trying to boot a NetInstall or NetRestore image over the network all works fine until the client tries to download the `kernelcache` file.

At block 3005, the client keeps sending ACKs for block 3004 (s. screenshot).
[image: Wireshark Capture]

**Edit:**
  There seem to be some problems loading the image, so here's a rough transcription:

```
Server -> Client: Data Packet, Block 3004
Client -> Server: Acknowledgement, Block 3004
Server -> Client: Data Packet, Block 3005
Client -> Server: Acknowledgement, Block 3004
Server -> Client: Data Packet, Block 3005
Client -> Server: Acknowledgement, Block 3004
Server -> Client: Data Packet, Block 3005
Client -> Server: Acknowledgement, Block 3004
```

The kernelcache file is below the (old) magic threshold of 32M.

Server:

- macOS 10.12.4
- Server 5.3

Client:

- macOS 10.12.3 (if that matters at all)
- MacBookPro12,1 (so nothing outdated)

Comment: Don't see the screenshot, sorry (broken image).

Do you have any other 10.12.4 images that work on this server? If so you can try copying the kernelcache from that one into this image's .nbi folder. I've used that to work around a goofy issue before.

As you were suggesting, I've seen NetBoot fail when the kernel cache is "too large." There's also a 5 minute time-out if it takes a long time to get the data, if that applies here.

Comment: @MacManager unfortunately there's no working image yet. I added the Wireshark capture in abbreviated text form to the question as well. That behaviour of TFTP looks to me like there's some other issue here though.

Comment: The screenshot appears now, I notice it says "Fragmented IP Protocol." Before this happens is there only a single ACK for each block? Thinking out loud, perhaps they're being split up and there are multiple ACKs for each piece it receives?

Comment: Yep, before that there was only one ACK per packet. It's also 'acknowledging' the wrong packet number.